# How to make datetime object timezone aware by GMT hours instead of location string

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I work with several computers which have their computer clocks running at different GMT times. In order for my code to run smoothly across the machines, the timezones have to be specified in the code for each computer. The current way of making a `datetime.datetime` object timezone aware is by using the `pytz.timezone.localise` function. For example,

```
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
```

This requires me to specify the timezone as a location string. I prefer working with GMT hours, instead of strings. Is there anyway to construct a timezone object using integers representing hours?

Comment: for one, I'd suggest to use `dateutil` instead of `pytz` since it's likely to be [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). dateutil will also be easier to replace with `zoneinfo` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There turns out to be timezone strings that have the GMT hour as part of the string, e.g. `Etc/GMT-9` (which can be found when you check pytz.all_timezones)

Now we can simply do

```
eastern = timezone(f'Etc/GMT{GMTHOUR}')
loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
```

where `GMTHOUR` is the timezone integer, which woulf be formatted into the string

Comment: ...other than that, you don't have to use an Etc timezone, you can simply use a `timedelta` that represents the UTC offset, e.g. `tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=9))`